# Problems using distcp and s3distcp with my EMR job that outputs to HDFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce, amazon-emr, emr

I've run a job on AWS's EMR, and stored the output in the EMR job's HDFS.  I am then trying to copy the result to S3 via distcp or s3distcp, but both are failing as described below. (Note: the reason I'm not just sending my EMR job's output directly to S3 is due to the (currently unresolved) problem I describe in [Where is my AWS EMR reducer output for my completed job (should be on S3, but nothing there)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169708/where-is-my-aws-emr-reducer-output-for-my-completed-job-should-be-on-s3-but-no)

For distcp, I run (following [this post's recommendation](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=34011&tstart=0)):

```
elastic-mapreduce --jobflow <MY-JOB-ID> --jar \
s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/distcp/distcp.jar \
    --args -overwrite \
    --args hdfs:///output/myJobOutput,s3n://output/myJobOutput \
    --step-name "Distcp output to s3"
```

In error log (/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/8), I get:

```
With failures, global counters are inaccurate; consider running with -i
Copy failed: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: <SOME-REQUEST-ID>, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Forbidden, S3 Extended Request ID: <SOME-EXT-REQUEST-ID>
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:548)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:288)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:170)
...
```

For s3distcp, I run (following [the s3distcp documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html)):

```
elastic-mapreduce --jobflow <MY-JOB-ID> --jar \
s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/s3distcp/1.0.4/s3distcp.jar \
--args '--src,/output/myJobOutput,--dest,s3n://output/myJobOutput'
```

In the error log (/mnt/var/log/hadoop/steps/9), I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Reducer task failed to copy 1 files: hdfs://10.116.203.7:9000/output/myJobOutput/part-00000 etc
        at com.amazon.elasticmapreduce.s3distcp.CopyFilesReducer.close(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:537)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:428)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:** Someone responding on the AWS Forums to a [post about a similar distcp error](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93486) mentions the IAM user user permissions, <strike>but I don't know what this means</strike> (**edit:** I haven't created any IAM users, so it is using the defaults); hopefully it helps pinpoint my problem.

**Update 2:** I noticed this error in namenode log file (when re-running s3distcp).. I'm going to look into default EMR permissions to see if it is my problem:

```
2012-06-24 21:57:21,326 WARN org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping (IPC Server handler 40 on 9000): got exception trying to get groups for user job_201206242009_0005
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: id: job_201206242009_0005: No such user

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:255)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:182)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:375)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:461)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getUnixGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.getGroups(ShellBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getGroupNames(UserGroupInformation.java:966)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.<init>(FSPermissionChecker.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:5160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkTraverse(FSNamesystem.java:5143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getFileInfo(FSNamesystem.java:1992)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.getFileInfo(NameNode.java:837)
    ...
```

**Update 3:** I contact AWS Support, and they didn't see a problem, so am now waiting to hear back from their engineering team. Will post back as I hear more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% positive, but after reviewing my commands above, I noticed that my destination on S3 does NOT specify a bucket name.  This appears to simply be a case of rookie-ism.

Comment: Ha! I think everybody who viewed your message supposed that "output" is a name of your bucket :)))

Answer (score 1):

Try this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12302277/658346). At least it worked for me. (I've successfully copied dir with 30Gb file).

Comment: I did happen to include the extra slash for my path, but as my answer to this question states, I think I simply left off the bucket name when specifying my S3 path :(  damn rookies!