# How to configure hadoop 1.2.1 with storage on Amazon S3?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I have tried to put the following in my core-site.xml file by following this wiki http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3, but my hadoop cannot make connection with S3n. I have hadoop 1.2.1 deployed on EC2 cluster. What is the correct way of configuring Hadoop with S3 storage? thanks a lot!

```
 <property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>s3://BUCKET</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId</name>
  <value>ID</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
  <value>SECRET</value>
</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to replace s3 with s3n in your configuration?

Try this:

```
    <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>s3n://BUCKET</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
      <value>ID</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
      <value>SECRET</value>
    </property>
```

By the way there're great explanations of the difference between s3 and s3n [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569455/difference-between-amazon-s3-and-s3n-in-hadoop)

Additionally you may need to start and stop HDFS cluster (not sure that there is a need to start it, as we don't use it anymore).