# How to copy from subdirectories using s3DistCp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, distcp

Trying to use `s3DistCp` to copy from `s3://my-bucket/dir1/` , `s3://my-bucket/dir2`, `s3://my-bucket/dir3`.

And all three DIRs has some files in them. Wanted to do something like:

```
hadoop jar s3distcp.jar --src s3://my-bucket/*/ --dest s3://my-bucket/some-other-dir/
```

But it generate an error saying that:

> 's3://my-bucket/*/' directory not found...

So does it mean `s3DistCp` doesn't take wildcards in paths? Is there any work around or any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Jason! It looks much nicer now : )

Comment: Can you get the files using s3cmd? Have you tried s3n?

Comment: how about writing a bash script that simply calls s3distcp multiple times with each of the source paths?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with s3n? [Difference between Amazon S3 and S3n in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10569455/difference-between-amazon-s3-and-s3n-in-hadoop)

Comment: No... I removed the trailing '/' but it is still generating "no such file or directory" error.